# Certain text looks bitty on PC

Tags: display, graphics-card

A few days ago, I found out that a few keys on my keyboard weren't working.
All the keys to the left of Q, A and Z including those keys. I then replaced this keyboard with a very old one that I had lying around. Ever since I did this, I noticed certain text rendered very bitty / pixely:

[image]

Now, is this just a co-incidence or is this something to do with maybe my LCD monitor / graphics card or keyboard?

As you can see in the image, other text looks fine ...
If I open up Notepad to see if the problem is with PLAIN TEXT ... it looks fine!
Even when I browse some websites, some text appears bitty, eg: when I choose tags for this post, you'll see the text looks bitty:

[image]
*original at http://pbrd.co/19nW4Ca*

NOTE: I've bought a new keyboard today and the problem remains

Comment: Here is a closeup of the text: http://pbrd.co/17h8RVs

Comment: new version inlined.

Comment: are these screenshots?

Comment: Yes, well the first screenshot was taken via PRINT SCREEN and then I zoomed into the text and took another screenshot to show you how the text is fked!

Comment: The tag around UNTITLED DOCUMENT is supposed to read TITLE... but as you can see it looks like I've printed this this screenshot using an old printer

Comment: Can someone explain why I got a downvote?

Comment: Did you install the latest Microsoft fix before this problem appeared?  If so, it's probably this problem: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286196/is-it-just-my-imagination-or-have-the-fonts-gotten-even-uglier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix available!!**

I installed the fix from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3037639 and everything is hunky-dory again.

Comment: Thanks Daniel... all is sorted now with that link to the fix. What irritates me is why couldn't microsoft automatically download/update the fix, when they automatically downloaded/updated the issue onto my PC!

Answer (score 1):

This is due to installing [KB3013455](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3013455).

You can do 2 things, either not use the Arial font or uninstall the windows update.

## Uninstall the windows update

To uninstall the windows update, do the following: Go to control panel, Programs and features.
On the left side, click `View installed updates`

From the list on the right, find KB3013455 and uninstall it.

Reboot the computer when it says so.

Comment: Does anyone know if using "ClearType" will help -- See http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/tune.aspx and https://www.winhelp.us/change-font-smoothing-in-windows.html

Comment: OK, just looked -- it appears that ClearType is already enabled for Vista.

Comment: It's kinda looking like ClearType was disabled by the fix.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! I ended up fixing the problem by downloading the update Windows6.0-KB3037639-x86.msu from this page http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45662 and my text quality is back to normal!